# Does laravel .env file inherits server env variables?

Tags: laravel, environment-variables

I'm a bit confused.

I can set server variables.
There is also laravel .env variables.

Because if I set on server, laravel .env changes doesnt show.
If I use only laravel .env no problem to change.

What is the relationship between them??

Comment: .env files are read with the library [dotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) which by default (and the way it is configured to be used in Laravel) will not override the system environment variables (e.g. the ones in $_ENV or $_SERVER).

Comment: That is what `.env` stands for. You don't need to specify credentials for like db or redis connection, some access_tokens in somewhere else. `.env` is not getting varibales from server, server gets it from `.env`

Comment: so SERVER environment variables = SYSTEM environment variables? and laravel will override its .env variables with SERVER vars?

Comment: It does not load anything from .env that is already set on the system so in practice yes. $_SERVER in PHP does contain the environment variables set on the server (the machine) as well as the webserver (e.g. apache or nginx) in addition to PHP specific variables like the current script path etc

Comment: thanks apokryfos. i need to study it more. but i think i'm getting there.

Comment: @TadasV. remember you can always check the documentation that is explaining this behaviour: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/configuration#environment-configuration

Comment: @matiaslauriti - i read it multiple times, but still couldn't get a clear understanding between server and lara env

Comment: okay, no worries! did you understand now or do you still have questions?